# What exactly is connoted with "bumper-sticker wisdom"?

Tags: meaning

Does "bumper-sticker wisdom" always have a negative connotation in the sense of "truisms/platitudes/bromides that are short enough to fit on a bumper sticker"? If not, what is usually connoted with this expression? Í'm still not sure about it after having consulted a couple of websites.

Comment: Interesting question!  To this US English speaker, yes, it means what you are asking about.  Something like "Something short that sounds clever but isn't really deep."

Comment: What makes you think that "truisms short enough to fit on a bumper sticker" is necessarily a **negative** thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone uses the phrase in a derogatory way, it means they think the opinion being discussed is too simple, or that it's a popular opinion not even worth talking about. (This is the connotation you mention in your question.) This might be because the speaker thinks it's an obvious truth, or that the owner of the car only has the opinion because they saw the bumper sticker.

While the phrase does often connote wisdom or opinions that are too simplified, it doesn't have to be that way. In [this article](https://feross.org/bumper-sticker-wisdom/),
the phrase doesn't carry that connotation. The author argues that many bumper stickers contradict that connotation, and do contain interesting or profound meanings.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the article you mention before I wrote my question, but still wasn't quite sure about the prevalent connotations connected with that phrase. I can see now that the connotations can be ambivalent.